# Undervolting PWM fan from 12V to 5V

Tags: pwm, noise, fan, undervoltage

What will happen if I feed a 12 Volts rated PWM fan with 5 V driving voltage?

Given all the other variables stay the same (PWM control signals) - will it reduce RPM? By how much?

What happens to the RPM range window? Will it shift downwards? Will it shrink?

Answer (score 4):

Running a PWM controllable fan designed for operation at +12V may run OK at a lower voltage as long as you do not go too low. PWM controlled fans have an IC chip inside and one or more hall sensors. When the applied voltage to the fan gets too low the IC chip will fail to operate correctly. I have found in some experiments that I have done that I was able to get the fans to operate OK at voltages down to about 6.2 volts. Below that the fans would not start reliably and the fan motor lacks torque.

I would personally recommend that you operate a 12V fan at 12V and then use the PWM feature to regulate the fan speed to the level you require.

Comment: The PWM fan header the fan is connected to, only allows the fan to go 1000 RPM at a minimum, which is too much for my situation. Hence the idea of undervolting.

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin: that doesn't happen to be a Supermicro motherboard does it?

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin - I would recommend that you simply source a fan with a lower speed range then. Do use care however when replacing an existing fan and not just make the judgement call based upon sound level. Many electrical components do need adequate airflow to ensure they stay cool enough.

Answer (score 2):

OK, just took the plunge and re-wired the fan from 12V to 5V.

To my surprise it did start no problem, and is going quite strong with more than sufficient torque - unlike another fan (non-PWM 120mm PSU fan), which doesn't start even at 7V by itself and the torque is very faint when eventually started manually.

Here are the actual experimental results:

Nominal 12V supply. RPM range was, as observed from the fan sensor wire monitoring: 1000-2500.

When modded to 5V, the RPM range got down to: 325-780. Not quite what I was hoping for (I'd be happier with at least 1k RPM at the top end), but still acceptable, at least for the winter time and especially considering the tremendously reduced fan noise level.

Note: the fan used is the Intel stock CPU HSF.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to vary by fan manufacturer and by fan. Some fans may spin, others may spin and stall, others may not start at all. These are the risks one takes when they operate devices outside of their specifications - behaviour is not guaranteed.

If you want guaranteed performance, build yourself a simple PWM circuit, run the fan with 12V and use the PWM to control the speed.

Answer (score -1):

One nice trick that can be useful is powering the fan between the 12V and 5V lines, so that it sees 7V that probably will fit perfectly for your application. The 5V line is probably designed to sink a little if not any current at all, but what actually happens is that the current flowing through the fan goes to the common terminal via one of the many other utilizers, and the 5V stabilization is still guaranteed by the switching circuit in the PSU.